# Passing arrays with RecyclerView Holder to Alertdialog

Tags: android, arrays, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

I am writing an Expandable Recycler View in which the code is slightly different from the usual Recycler View. The bind method in my code is defined in ViewHolder. Everything seems to be writing correctly and I can’t understand what my mistake is. I pass arrays from RecyclerView to AlertDialog but for some reason the application crashes. Here is the code for my View Holder with the error string indicated:

```
public class AnalysisViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder {
    HtmlTextView textView;
    FrameLayout frame;
    Context c;
public AnalysisViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_rc);
    frame = itemView.findViewById(R.id.frame);
}
public void bind(final Analysys analysys){
    textView.setHtml(analysys.name);
    frame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {// here
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder aa = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
            aa.setTitle(analysys.name);
            aa.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(analysys.analysis));
            aa.setNegativeButton(c.getString(R.string.back), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Мy Stacktrace:

```
2019-08-29 22:06:45.494 29861-29861/com.vn.iambulance.prototype_20 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.vn.iambulance.prototype_20, PID: 29861
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:224)
        at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:474)
        at com.vn.iambulance.prototype_20.adapter_analysis.AnalysisViewHolder.bind(AnalysisViewHolder.java:28)
        at com.vn.iambulance.prototype_20.adapter_analysis.AnalysisAdapter.onBindChildViewHolder(AnalysisAdapter.java:36)
        at com.vn.iambulance.prototype_20.adapter_analysis.AnalysisAdapter.onBindChildViewHolder(AnalysisAdapter.java:13)
        at com.thoughtbot.expandablerecyclerview.ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter.java:82)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1083)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1231)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:1041)
2019-08-29 22:06:45.495 29861-29861/com.vn.iambulance.prototype_20 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3380)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2849)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1897)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8514)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7076)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Answer (score 0):

your error is this :-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
```

and I asking of you. are your solving it ...

```
AlertDialog.Builder aa = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
```

Your right line is here ...

```
AlertDialog.Builder aa = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

In your project requirement to create constructor within the activity to the adapter. declare in activity or adapter context and this problem solved ...